# Is PHP's error_log dependent on the OS, config file or something else?

Tags: linux, windows, php, configuration, log-files

I have two HTTP servers:

1. Live LAMP server.
2. Local WAMP server.

When an error occurs on the live server PHP will generate an `error_log` file in the directory of where the script error occurred. The local server does not do that.

Is the error_log dependent on the OS, PHP configuration or something else and how can I *effectively* verify the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be set to a value at compile time, and it can be set by configuration, so both is possible. Additionally, it can be modified at runtime, or by the webserver configuration. Create a simple php file just containing `phpinfo()` and call it with your browser. It will show you both the configuration and the runtime value.

```php
<?php
phpinfo();
```

[image]

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19520881/212107):

> **master** is either the value compiled into PHP, or set via a main php.ini directive. I.e., the value that's in effect when PHP fires up, before it executes any of your code.
>
> **local** is the value that's currently in effect at the moment you call phpinfo(). This local value is the end result of any overrides that have taken place via ini_set() calls, php_value directives in httpd.conf/.htaccess, etc.

It will also show you all ini files that have been loaded.

Comment: No value on the local server and a custom value on the live, okay. Working to verify...

Comment: I added `ini_set('error_log', 'error.log');` in a PHP file I'm testing, `error_log = 'error.log'` in the *only* php.ini file, restarted the Apache server and still not seeing anything after I use `echo $a;` which is not set. I have error reporting set to maximum sensitivity on the local server. Suggestions please?

Comment: This worked: `error_log = 'D:\wamp\logs\php_general.log'` in the `php.ini` file with `error_log('test');` in `test.php`; thank you.